# parent-child based range ordering in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sheet of data:

[image: Data]

As you can see, I have 5 parents, each with their own subtree/range. I want to re-order these parent/subtrees, given a parent-order association in another sheet. My logic is to iterate over the rows until I see another parent, selecting the range, and storing it in some temporary range at the index proportional to total row and range length. The order association sheet looks like:

[image: order]

I was thinking of storing this new order in some temporary column in my desired sheet, overwriting the original column then clearing the temporary, but this seems inefficient, and I'm not sure how to implement this logic efficiently in VBA, or if there is an easier logic possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Logic implementation:

```
i = 2
While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting").Cells(i, 3) <> ""
looking = 0
j = 8
While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Cells(j, 3) <> ""
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Cells(j, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting").Cells(i, 3) Then
        start_row = j
        looking = 1
    End If
    If looking = 1 And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Cells(j, 3) <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting").Cells(i, 3) Then
        end_row = j - 1
    End If
Wend
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Range("start_row:end_row").Cut
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Range("1:1").Insert
Wend
```

Comment: Maybe iterate over your order association table instead. Sort the order association table by the descending order of the **Order** column, go find the parent, scan until you see the next parent (remembering the first and last rows) then cut and paste the rows at the top of the sheet?

Comment: But won't this overwrite other data?

Comment: Sorry, do an insert, not a paste. (Delete the rows and insert them at the top. Since you are going backwards through the order list, this will push them down, ending with the first one at the top.)

Comment: I'm intreagued about inserting but I'm not sure how to implement this, how would you store the data? You'd have to delete before inserting but where would it go in the meantime

Comment: I'll make answer...

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your order association table in descending order by the **Order** column.

This is pseudocode, because I'm assuming you have most of your code already in place.

```
Loop through your Order Association table
    Set state to Looking
    Loop through the rows of the Root table
        If Root Name matches Association Name
            Remember the row (Start Row)
            Set state to Not Looking
        endif
        if State is Not Looking and Root Name does not match Association Name
            Remember the previous row (End Row)
        endif
    End Loop
    Range(Start Row:End Row).Cut
    Range("1:1").Insert
End Loop
```

Well, this turned out to be a bit trickier than I expected, but this works in my sample data:

```
Sub SortWeights()

    Dim formatRow As Integer        ' Current row in ordered list of parents
    Dim weightRow As Integer        ' Current row while sorting weights
    Dim startRow As Integer         ' First row in weights group
    Dim endRow As Integer           ' Last row in weights group
    Dim weightsSheet As Worksheet   ' Worksheet containing weights
    Dim formatSheet As Worksheet    ' Worksheet containing ordered parent weights
    Dim looking As Boolean          ' True while gathering child rows
    Dim doShift As Boolean          ' True if weights group needs to be moved
    Dim candidate As Range          ' Candidate weight
    Dim sortingWeight As Range      ' Reformatted sorting weight name

    Const firstFormatRow As Integer = 1     'First row in ordered list of parents
    Const lastFormatRow As Integer = 3      'Last row in ordered list of parents
    Const firstWeightRow As Integer = 1     'First row in list of weights to be sorted
    Const lastWeightRow As Integer = 8      'Last row in list of weights to be sorted
    Const weightNameColumn As Integer = 3   'Column with parent names to be sorted
    Const formatNameColumn As Integer = 3   'Column with parent names in ascending order

    Set weightsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Weights")
    Set formatSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting")

    formatRow = lastFormatRow

    ' Loop through the list of ordered parent weights
    Do Until formatRow < firstFormatRow

        ' Reset everything
        looking = False
        doShift = False
        startRow = 0
        endRow = 0
        Set sortingWeight = formatSheet.Cells(formatRow, formatNameColumn)

        ' Loop through the list of all weights
        For weightRow = firstWeightRow To lastWeightRow

            Set candidate = weightsSheet.Cells(weightRow, weightNameColumn)

            ' If match found, start counting
            If candidate.Value = sortingWeight.Value Then
                ' If the match is in the first row, it is already in place, skip it.
                If weightRow = 1 Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    startRow = weightRow
                    looking = True
                    doShift = True
                End If
            End If

            ' If gathering children...
            If looking Then
                ' If this is the last row, it is the end of the group.
                If weightRow = lastWeightRow Then
                    endRow = weightRow
                ' Otherwis, if this is a new group, the previous row was the end.
                ElseIf candidate.IndentLevel = 0 And candidate <> sortingWeight Then
                    endRow = weightRow - 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If

        Next weightRow

        ' Only do the cut and insert if necessary
        If doShift Then
            weightsSheet.Range(CStr(startRow) & ":" & CStr(endRow)).Cut
            weightsSheet.Range(CStr(firstWeightRow) & ":" & CStr(firstWeightRow)).Insert
        End If

        ' Do the next parent.
        formatRow = formatRow - 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

You will need to update your constants to match whatever is in your sheets. You could, if you wanted, make the constants variable and use the UsedRange property of the worksheet object to set those values, if you want. That would be a bit more dynamic, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question.

Let me know how it goes. Hope it gets you where you need to be.

Comment: Two followup questions, is this pseudo implementable in a way that maintains cell formatting? Also, how can this be changed for ascending order?

Comment: The formatting stays with the rows that are cut and inserted. You could sort your list in ascending order and loop backwards through the list.

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with my code, some of the hardcoded column values are because of my own formatting, but is there an implementation issue anywhere? I updated the post.

Comment: One thing that I notice is that `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Range("start_row:end_row").Cut` should be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Range(CStr(start_row) & " :" & CStr(end_row)).Cut`

Comment: I'm still exploring this and have at least one question. In your example, are Lima and Delta in the same column and just indented by spacing or is each child row shifted by one column?

Comment: Everything is in the same column, but the tree structure is denoted by using InsertIndent

Comment: It also seems like I have an infinite loop going on... the running doesn't stop and as far as I can tell my loop has a definitive stop value. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated my answer providing code that actually works in my sample spreadsheet. The comments should help you sort out how to make it work for your environment. If not, I'm here.

Comment: My apologies for the delay. I'm having issues with the output. It seems like insert will insert at row 1, however my actual "column" of values starts at row 8. Is it possible to adjust the insertion location?

Comment: Adjust the constants in the code to match the setup in your worksheet. That is why they are there.

Comment: I have, they are respectively (1, 5, 8, 21, 3, 3). I call this subroutine, and it inserts items before row 8, which is what the constant "firstweightRow" is set to, and I'm not sure why this is the case

Comment: Oops.  Change `weightsSheet.Range("1:1").Insert` to `weightsSheet.Range(CStr(firstWeightRow) & ":" & CStr(firstWeightRow)).Insert` and see if that helps.  I will adjust the line in my answer momentarily. Sorry about that.

Comment: I thought that was the case but wasn't sure, thanks! My final question is if I wanted to make my lastWeightRow dynamic, what would be the most efficient way to get the last value in a column that isn't null? I know I could loop over until I find it, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: `weightsSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` might do the trick for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179411/discussion-between-evariste-galois-and-stonegiant).